# How to Post on my facebook wall by clicking a button in an android app?

Tags: android, android-facebook

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("facebook:/post/hello");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I want to post on my facebook wall, when I click a button. But the above code is just opening my wall. I want to post on my wall when I click a button. Please help me .

Comment: so you just want to post directly to the facebook without opening any facebook dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Using the feed dialog is now recommended by facebook team, if you are ok with an extra dialog of what you post on facebook, you can use this method. But be sure we have given all the permission and have facebook api permission and sdk.

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("name", "Product shared from Bee2buy");
            params.putString("caption",
                    appPref.getData("share_title"));

            params.putString("link", "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                    + appPref.getData("share_img"));
            params.putString("picture",
                    "http://www.saznaitsols.com/site_uploads/product/"
                            + appPref.getData("share_img"));

            WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                    ShareData.this, currentSession, params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                // and the post Id.
                                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                if (postId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ShareData.this,
                                            "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            ShareData.this
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                // User clicked the "x" button
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                // Generic, ex: network error
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ShareData.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }



                    }).build();
            feedDialog.show();
        }
```

This might help [facebook share on wall](https://gist.github.com/jacklt/6700201)